# Downloading a file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got the following method whose purpose is to submit a post request using an invisible form. This request is to download a file, which does not have a URL but taken from a binary file store dynamically. The server side is Java Servlet.

```
function postCall(url, params) {
    var newForm = jQuery('<form>', {
            'method':'POST',
            'action': url
        });

    for(key in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            newForm.append(jQuery('<input>', {
                'id': key,
                'value': params[key],
                'type': 'hidden'
            }));
        }
    }

    newForm.submit();
}
```

When this method is called, the server side didn't receive the requst. I think there must be something wrong with this code.

Comment: @Nix `<form>` creates a new form element, without the angle brackets it just selects all existing forms... that's not what he wants

Comment: Shouldn't the form be appended to the page before being submitted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only inputs with a `name` are submitted to server. Try this:

```
newForm.append(jQuery('<input>', {
    'name': key, //<-- change to name instead of id
    'value': params[key],
    'type': 'hidden'
}));
```

Also, for IE, you must also append the form to the document before submitting:

```
newForm.appendTo("body").submit();
```